# ESP32 Project with Delayed Telegram Message Sending – Is a 20-Second Watchdog Timeout Appropriate?

Tags: telegram, esp32, watchdog

I have a project with ESP32 that, under certain conditions on a GPIO input pin, sends a message via Telegram. Generally, the execution of the loop takes less than a millisecond, except when it sends a Telegram message, which averages around 8 seconds. Yes, 8 seconds, as I understand that the HTTP protocol must be carried out.

Since the project involves the ESP32 being unsupervised for a long time, I have thought about using a watchdog. **Do you think it is advisable to set the watchdog to 30 seconds?**

Why 30 seconds, well, because if the message fails sending the message it would try again 3 times.